# selected Item of DropDownList

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, drop-down-menu

How can I get selected Item of my DropDownList?

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Doctors", "User", FormMethod.Get))
{
    <input name="pageNumber" type="hidden" value="1" /><text>Hospital:</text><br />

    @Html.DropDownList("HospitalId", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.HospitalList, new { style = "width:90%" }) <br />

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-mini"> Search </button>
}
```

Comment: See my DDL tutorial http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/javascript/working-with-the-dropdownlist-box-and-jquery/using-the-dropdownlist-helper-with-aspnet-mvc and http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rickandy/archive/2012/01/09/cascasding-dropdownlist-in-asp-net-mvc.aspx

Answer (score 0):

This question isn't very clear as to when / where you want to get your drop down list item.

I will assume you want to pick it up in the controller for now. What you will need to do is make sure its included in your post to the controller and is using the correct name to be picked up when the form is read server side.

Here is an example:

```
@Html.DropDownList("SubworkType", "Select Work Item", new { @Id = "SubworkId" , @Name = "SubworkId"  })
```

If You are looking to grab the selected value on the view side you could do something like this:

```
var workerType = $("#WorkerTypeFilter option:selected").val()
```

Answer (score 0):

It should simply be accessible as a parameter in your Controller's action method.

```
public ActionResult Doctors(string pageNumber, string HospitalId)
{
    // make use of HospitalId
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer to avoid dynamic variables like `ViewBag`/`ViewData` and stick with strong types.

Use a ViewModel

```
public class AssignDoctorViewModel
{
  //Other Properties also
  public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Hospitals { set;get;}
  public int SelectedHospital { set;get;}
}
```

And in my `GET` Action method, I would return this with the filled properties

```
public ActionResult AssignDoctor
{
  var vm=new AssignDoctorViewModel();
  vm.Hospitals= new[]
    {
          new SelectListItem { Value = "1", Text = "Florance" },
          new SelectListItem { Value = "2", Text = "Spark" },
          new SelectListItem { Value = "3", Text = "Henry Ford" },
    };
    // can replace the above line with loading data from Data access layer.
   return View(vm);
}
```

Now in your view which is strongly typed to our ViewModel class

```
@model AssignDoctorViewModel
@using(Html.BeginForm())
{
   @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.SelectedHospital, Model.Hospitals, "Select..")
  <input type="submit" value="save" />      
}
```

Now in your `HTTPPOST` Action method, you can get the Selected value by accessing the `SelectedHospital` Property

```
public ActionResult AssignDoctor(AssignDoctorViewModel model)
{ 
  //check for model.SelectedHospital value

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Shyju's answer is good, I just want to expand on what Shyju has said with some pointers.

Use a view model per view with just the data that you need, anything not used please remove.

Your domain model could look like this:

```
public class Hospital
{
     public int Id { get; set; }

     public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Your view model could look like this:

```
public class DoctorHospitalViewModel
{
     public int HospitalId { get; set; }

     public IEnumerable<Hospital> Hospitals { get; set; }
}
```

Your view could look like this (I put the dropdown in a table for display purposes):

```
<table>
     <tr>
          <td class="edit-label">Hospital <span class="required">**</span></td>
          <td>
               @Html.DropDownListFor(
                    x => x.HospitalId,
                    new SelectList(Model.Hospital, "Id", "Name", Model.HospitalId),
                    "-- Select --"
               )
               @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.HospitalId)
          </td>
     </tr>
</table>
```

Your controller might look like this and assuming you are wanting to use this dropdown in a create view:

```
public class HospitalController : Controller
{
     private readonly IHospitalRepository hospitalRepository;

     public HospitalController(IHospitalRepository hospitalRepository)
     {
          // Check that hospitalRepository is not null

          this.hospitalRepository = hospitalRepository;
     }

     public ActionResult Create()
     {
          DoctorHospitalViewModel viewModel = new DoctorHospitalViewModel
          {
               Hospitals = hospitalRepository.GetAll()
          };

          return View(viewModel);
     }

     [HttpPost]
     public ActionResult Create(DoctorHospitalViewModel viewModel)
     {
          // Check that viewModel is not null

          if (!ModelState.IsValid)
          {
               viewModel.Hospitals = hospitalRepository.GetAll();

               return View(viewModel);
          }

          // Do what ever needs to be done
          // You can get the selected hospital id like this
          int selectedHospitalId = viewModel.HospitalId;

          return RedirectToAction("List");
     }
}
```

I hope this helps.